# Server side java code for upload multiple image from android

Tags: java, android, jsp, servlets

I get code from [android code](http://mayanklangalia.blogspot.in/2014/04/how-to-upload-multiple-images-on-php.html)

below is part of that code.

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            String url = "http://192.168.1.21:8080/uploadimageserverside/upload.jsp";
            int i = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(map.get(i));
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            entity = new MultipartEntity();

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            entity.addPart("user_id", new StringBody("199"));
            entity.addPart("club_id", new StringBody("10"));
            entity.addPart("club_image", new ByteArrayBody(data,"image/jpeg", params[1]));

            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
            sResponse = EntityUtils.getContentCharSet(response.getEntity());

            System.out.println("sResponse : " + sResponse);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (dialog.isShowing())
                dialog.dismiss();
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage(), e);

        }
        return sResponse;
    }
```

but I don't know how to code in server side for java to read file and write. Please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can using [Jersey Framework](https://jersey.java.net/) for building your owner Restful, if you don't know working with backend you need install some tools to configure  Restful see below :

**Download and Install**: [Apache Tomcat](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/tomcat_howto.html), [Jersey  - hello-world-example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/rest/jersey/jersey-hello-world-example/)

**Follow this tutorial:**

[jersey-rest-web-service-to-upload-multiple-files](https://crispcode.wordpress.com/2012/07/27/jersey-rest-web-service-to-upload-multiple-files/)